# Zsh prompt char disappears when window resizes or prompt otherwise resets

Tags: command-line, zsh

I have a simple prompt in Zsh. It only contains the prompt char `»` (replaced with `N` when in normal mode, as I use ZLE's Vi mode).

Whenever the window resizes, the prompt char disappears as if it were backspaced. This happens regardless of whether I'm in normal mode or not.

How can I fix this?

My prompt theme (minimal reproducible case):

```
# Functionality for displaying normal mode indicator in Vi mode.
function zle-line-init zle-keymap-select {
  local return_status="»"
  zle reset-prompt
}
zle -N zle-line-init
zle -N zle-keymap-select
# End Vi mode functionality

PROMPT='${return_status}'
```

Comment: I also see this behaviour if I run `zle reset-prompt` on a timeout (using `TMOUT`/`TRAPALRM`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's probably happening is during a reset of the prompt not initiated by `zle-line-init` or `zle-keymap-select` the `local` variable `return_status` would be undefined.

Of course, this would mean that your `PROMPT` is now empty.

Removing the `local` qualifier should fix your problem and give you back your beautiful, unicode prompt character in full glory :)